# Youtube "failed to convert" using ffmpeg CLI

Tags: linux, command-line, ffmpeg, youtube

I'm using ffmpeg to split videos to comply with their length but whenever I upload them it says "failed to convert". I'm using this settings

`ffmpeg -i "${file}" -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libmp3lame -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:13:00 -f mp4 "/home/ras/education/${args[0]}_${startingfrom}_Parte_01_04.mp4"`

`ffmpeg -i "${file}" -ar 22050 -vcodec libx264  -acodec libmp3lame  -ss 00:13:00  -f mp4 "/home/ras/education/${args[0]}_${startingfrom}_Parte_02_04.mp4"`
and so on...

Thing is I really have tried different codecs but it fails miserably.. tried with -vcodec copy -acodec copy, mjpeg and still don't get it right.. so I'm asking if any users have worked this out.

any help, suggestion, etc is really appreciated, note that I would really like to keep it in command line since there's a good amount to convert, btw if someone has a better title feel free to edit it

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ffmpeg -i mymovie.mpg -ar 22050 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32K -r 25 -s 320x240 -vcodec flv -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:13:00 new.flv
```